# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried a lot to solve this error, I didn't able to solve this error 
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"
during Execution.
[Getting Only this Exception all time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn20x.png)

here is my connection string which gives the details database.and I am using code first approch. so, 
[connectionstring with database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1JsJ.png)

Comment: try modifying you query like this :
employeeContext.Employees.Where(r=>r.EmployeeId==id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo or special characters in the connection string? E.g. try to delete space between ; and "integrated". Try to set SSPI of false instead of true. If doesn't help - try to delete integrated security completely and see what happens.